# Symfony : share a non-entity object between fixtures

Tags: php, symfony, fixtures

On Symfony 6, we can easly share an entty object through several fixtures class with [the methods `addReference` and `getReference`](https://symfony.com/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/current/index.html#sharing-objects-between-fixtures). But theses methods handle only entities class managed by the entityManager.

If I create a simple value in a variable (an integer, a string) initialized during the first fixture, how can I pass the variable to the next fixtures called during the `./bin/console d:fixture:load` script ?

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1):

`addReference()` and `getReference` are accessible by all your fixture classes, because they are implemented in a common base class `Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture`.

If you want to share more than that, just make use of the same idea:
**Introduce your own parent** class into the hierarchy and store everything you want to share on that parent:

```php
abstract class MyFixturesParent extends AbstractFixture 
{
  protected int $mySharedInt = 1;
}
```

and implement your Fixtures as children of that parent

```php
class MyFixtures extends MyFixturesParent
{
}
```

Comment: hmmm when I try this approach, I get this error when I run the 'fixture load' script : `The "App\DataFixtures\MyFixturesParent" fixture class is trying to be loaded, but is not available. Make sure this class is defined as a service and tagged with "doctrine.fixture.orm".`

Comment: In a standard symfony setup adding an abstract parent to all fixture classes should work out of the box. You should probably check your services.yml and debug Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Loader\SymfonyFixturesLoader to find out why it tries to load that abstract class as a fixtures service in your app.